# Javascript .includes method on an array within an object

Tags: reactjs

I want to filter through an array and retrieve items if their filters match. However it does not work.

```
const wanted=["apple"]
const items = [
  {
    "name": "Iphone"
    "filters": ["phone","apple"]
  },
  {
    "name": "samsung12"
    "filters": ["samsung12","samsung"]
  },
]

let desiredList = items.filter((val) => wanted.includes(val.filters));
```

Any ideas on how i could get this to work?

Comment: You sure `items` is an array?

Comment: @technophyle edited it yes its an array with many objects but simplified it in demo

Comment: `includes` method doesn't work like that. See documentation again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if any of the filters contains a value in `wanted`:

```js
const wanted = ["apple"]
const items = [{
  "name": "Iphone",
  "filters": ["phone", "apple"]
}, {
  "name": "samsung12",
  "filters": ["samsung12", "samsung"]
}];

let desiredList = items.filter((item) => item.filters.some((f) => wanted.includes(f)));

console.log(desiredList);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const wanted="apple"
const items = [
"name": "Iphone"
"filters": ["phone","apple"]
]

let desiredList = 
items.filter((val)=> 
val.filters.includes(wanted) )
```

Comment: `wanted` is supposed to be an array, though.

Comment: wanted is an array but thanks for help manage to solve

Comment: Thats the point, based on his code example I though that the problem is declaring wanted as an array !

Answer (score 1):

simply you need to filter your items searching the required field, then map the result using .map for each result

here you can check it

```js
let abc = document.querySelectorAll('div')

const wanted=["apple"]
const items = [{
  "name": "Iphone",
  "filters": ["phone","apple"]
},{
  "name": "Iphone",
  "filters": ["phone","sony"]
},{
  "name": "Iphone",
  "filters": ["phone","samsung"]
}]

items.filter((val) => val["filters"].includes(wanted[0])).map((item) => { item? abc[0].innerHTML += item.name+"<br />"+item.filters : console.log("none") })
```

```html
<div></div>
```